# Minimizing sum of two functions, minimize one and maximize the other.

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, maxima-minima

I'm new in optimization and I have a problem involving minimizing the sum of two functions f(x) and g(x). The objective function must be in such a way that f(x) has to be minimized and g(x) maximized, besides g(x) has a constant $\beta$ that determines it's importance ($\beta \in [0,1]$)

I have read that one solution is an objective function like this

\begin{equation}
f(x)- \beta g(x)
\end{equation}

and also found that could be

\begin{equation}
f(x)+ \frac{\beta}{g(x)}
\end{equation}

But I'am not really sure. Could you please help me? or provide me some book or anything in order to understand more about the optimization involving this case.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you not understand how these two example objectives can help accomplish this goal? In your problem, do both functions take the same input variable(s)?

Comment: Both functions will take the same inputs and the thing I don't understand is  if the objective functions I wrote are  correct or not. This is new to me so I really don't understand how I could write the objective function. I found this comment about minimizing while maximizing at the same time : "One way is to minimize (maximize) their difference, another one is minimizing one plus reciprocal of the other, etc." But I don't understand how it works. Thanks.

Comment: Someone any idea?